# Can you explain why plotting $\cos(\cos(90 \sqrt{x}))$ looks like this?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Can you explain why plotting $\cos(\cos(90 \sqrt{x}))$ looks like this:

[image: graph of \cos(\cos(90 \sqrt{x}))]

(from [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/?eqs=ACU3QiUyMnN0EGF0ZXMACSUzQQglNUIEAzIydGWAeHQlMjhjbwAZADkqYnJhY2tlIQQRbiUyQ4AcOTCAJTI5KnNxcgQ07RAweAATAAMqEA8ACwADLWAOMgBrBJYyKAl0cgR1ZQAZMTExNDmFAAgzAAQwLjc1AAccJTUEzgB5EDAycGkJBD81RBgcLUluZmBpbml0eQQYADEyjjIkERgpDAkyMmUASQ0AA0MAWQBWQzEwJQcAGgwDCD1zZXR0aYRuZwEiMiUzQQ1NkHhtaW4EXjNBAAYALTAuMTYwMzSDAKUISDIyeG1hAQcBCC8yMjQuODM5qDY1NwAqJQhReSg9ADIuMzQwOTA4AyAfID0yLjY1OTAWOQBYAANDACRjaGvAX2xhYmVsEJARKeEQGmdyaWQACwCoLBgMYXgV-xwYYW5nbMBlX3R5cGUMMgAGQHJhZGlhbgAJJQEIqWdyYXBoX3QAeXBlJTIyJTMAQSUyMmNhcnQAZXNpYW4lMjIAJTJDJTIyY28AdmVyX3Zpc2kAYmxlJTIyJTMAQWZhbHNlJTcARCU3RAAA))

Comment: what is there to explain?

Comment: Why it has compression , unlike normal cos , it also expands 
in the spaces between the peaks

Comment: It's like Longitudinal Waves
but without compression

Comment: Zooming near $0$ should make it look more like our mind picture of what it should look like.

Comment: @xsari3x: Well, the compression is because you precomposed the cosine with the square root. ;)

Comment: The change in frequency is due to the square-root.

Comment: Ehm , what's "precomposition " ?

Comment: The cosine of $0$ is $1$, so that's at least part of the explanation.

Comment: so the square root will make the change in the frequency ?? How , I'm intending to generate this signal through hardware :) ?

Comment: @Rasmus check the  http://bit.ly/rbiyJs , u will find the plot

Comment: @xsari3x: Precomposing a function $g$ with a function $f$ just means to perform the function $f$ before performing $g$.

Comment: @Rasmus: The square root of even a smallish number like the $0.0025$ that you mention, is kind of big, in the sense that after you multiply by $90$ you are seriously away from $0$.   By zoom I mean *really* zoom, like $[0,10^{-10}]$. Then we get about $0.54$, no more wiggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect it to look like a Cos(x) for example because the argument $\cos(90 \sqrt{x})$ is not linear, and is itself cyclic. Here is the graph of $\cos(90 \sqrt{x})$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As $x$ changes, $\sqrt{x}$ changes at a varying rate <s>that approaches $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$.  You can see that by realizing that $y = \pm\sqrt{x}$ is the same as $x=y^2$, and that's a parabola with a vertical tangent at $x=y=0$.</s>  Therefore it oscillates very fast when $x$ is near $0$.  As $x$ moves away from $0$, then $\sqrt{x}$ changes more slowly as $x$ changes, so this oscillates more slowly.

$\cos(\cos(90\sqrt{0}))= \cos 1 \approx 0.54,$ so it starts at $0.54$, and returns to $0.54$ whenever $90\sqrt{x}$ returns to something whose cosine is $1$.  The function returns to $1$ whenever $90\sqrt{x}$ returns to something whose cosine is $0$.

<s>The infinite rate of change at $x=0$ means the graph will have a vertical tangent at $x=0$, but does not mean it oscillates infinitely many times between $0$ and any particular positive value. The reasons for this can be seen with a little thought. In other words,</s> you should be able to actually *count* the oscillations between any positive argument and $0$.  The number of such oscillations is large because of the "90".

Comment: Dear Michael, I think "The infinite rate of change at $x=0$ means the graph will have a vertical tangent at $x=0$" is not true. The reason being that cosine has derivative $0$ at $0$.

Comment: You're right: I just computed the limit of the derivative at $0$.  It's got a numerator and denominator that both approach $0$, and the limit is a finite positive number.  So it's increasing pretty fast at $x=0$, but not infinitely fast.